# Sequential Search array out of bound issue in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, sequential

I implemented a sequential search in java. But, i am facing array index out of bound exception problem.

when i enter the correct number, the program is working fine. But, when i press a number which is not within the array, the program crashes because of  "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

```
public class Sequential {
public static void search (int arr[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int key;
    int N = arr.length;
    int element = 0;

    System.out.prinln("Enter the number that you want to search: ");
    key = in.nextInt();

    while (key != arr[element] && element <= N) 
    {
        element++;
    }

    if(element > N)
        {System.out.println("not found, try again...");}
    else 
        {System.out.println("found, it's in index # " + element);}
}
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 34, 37, 77 };
    search(arr);
}
}
```

Comment: add one more condition to this `(key != arr[element] && element <= N) ` to prevent out of bounds. Something like `key < N`

Comment: @Kon i used both `element < N ` and `element  <= N` none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as such has few issues, please look at my modified code. Should help you.

```
public static void search (int arr[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int key;
    int N = arr.length;
    int element = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter the number that you want to search: ");
    key = in.nextInt();
    boolean found = false;
    while (element < N) 
    {
        if(key == arr[element]){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        element++;
    }

    if(!found)
        {System.out.println("not found, try again...");}
    else 
        {System.out.println("found, it's in index # " + element);}
}
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 34, 37, 77 };
    search(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (element < N && key != arr[element] )
```

This doesn't work:

```
while (key != arr[element] && element < N )
```

Because when `elements` gets to the value of `N` this code `key != arr[element]` will still be executed and calling `arr[arr.length]` throws the exception.